# SQL getting the last item by date

Tags: sql

I have a query that I had working on one item, then I wiped the dataset and started over and now I can't get it to pull any data at all.
The query is basically:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLEA 
       LEFT JOIN TABLEB 
              ON TABLEA.ID = TABLEB.ID 
WHERE  TABLEA.ID = 1 
       AND TABLEB.DATE = (SELECT MAX(TABLEB.DATE) 
                          FROM   TABLEB 
                          WHERE  TABLEA.ID = 1)
```

TableB tracks changes and has hundreds of entries per ID.  I want a single row of the last chronological item pertaining to that ID.
If there is a better way to do this then awesome but I'd really like to know why this specific query isn't working.  When I run this query:

```
SELECT MAX(TABLEB.DATE) 
FROM   TABLEB 
       LEFT JOIN TABLEB 
              ON TABLEA.ID = TABLEB.ID 
WHERE  TABLEA.ID = 1
```

I get the proper value of the last date in the dataset.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL?

Comment: Go with CTE. Pretty much all latest versions of DB engines can handle this, except for MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * 
from tableA as a
    left outer join tableB as b on b.ID = a.ID
where
    b.Date = (select max(t.Date) from tableB as t WHERE t.ID = a.id)
    -- and a.ID = 1 if you need it
```

if you just need date from tableB, you can do

```
select * 
from tableA as a
    left outer join (
        select max(t.Date) as Date, t.ID from tableB as t group by t.ID
    ) as b on b.ID = a.ID
-- where a.ID = 1 if you need it
```

if you can use `row_number` function (you can change common table expression to subquery):

```
with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by a.ID order by b.Date desc) as rn
    from tableA as a
        left outer join tableB as b on b.ID = a.ID        
    -- where a.ID = 1 if you need it
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

if you're using SQL Server version >= 2005:

```
select * 
from tableA as a
    outer apply (
        select top 1 t.*
        from tableB as t
        where t.ID = a.ID
        order by t.Date desc
    ) as b
-- where a.ID = 1 if you need it
```

Please note using aliases in all subqueries.

About your initial query, I think you has an typo there:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLEA 
       LEFT JOIN TABLEB 
              ON TABLEA.ID = TABLEB.ID 
WHERE  TABLEA.ID = 1 
       AND TABLEB.DATE = (SELECT MAX(TABLEB.DATE) 
                          FROM   TABLEB 
                          WHERE  TABLEA.ID = 1) -- <-- Do you mean TABLEB.ID = 1 ??
```

Comment: This is amazing.  Thank you so much.  The first answer worked perfectly.  Now I just have to research why it worked and buy an SQL book.

Comment: @Keith what RDBMS do you using? SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA LEFT JOIN
     tableB
     ON tableA.ID = tableB.ID
WHERE tableA.ID = 1
ORDER BY tableB.Date desc
LIMIT 1;
```